# I have list of items. I have to show these items in two panels based on item type. My current code is

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div repeat="item in items | filter:{itemtype: 'icon'}">
     {{item.name}}
</div>

<div repeat="item in items | filter:{itemtype: 'text'}">
     {{item.name}}
</div>
```

//Now I have to display div's only if some items are available for particular type. I don't know how to handle this. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but it is much better to separate arrays already in your controller, otherwise these (possibly heavy) operations will run on each $digest:

```
<div g-if="(items | filter:{itemtype: 'icon'}).length">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{itemtype: 'icon'}" n>
         {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>

<div g-if="(items | filter:{itemtype: 'text'}).length">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{itemtype: 'text'}">
         {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, Thank u for response. I will separate the arrays